# the return from the form doest appeare in the backend side of my code

Tags: php

I am working on a small project to learn more about HTTP request methods using PHP. As a simple example, I want to take the value from user input and do text transformation on it, then return it to the user.

**html**

```html
<form action="index.php"    method="GET">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" name="name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

**php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $result = strtoupper($name);
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

When I click on submit, nothing happens. I checked `var_dump($_POST)` but it still returns nothing. What am I missing?

I also did a check on dumping the entire `$_POST` array but no value is printed out.

Comment: Typo: `method="GET"` does not match `$_POST`

Comment: [The  placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: As @Quentin pointed out, you have used 'GET' method in your HTML form so the `$_POST` array will be empty.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You form request is going through **GET** method and not **POST**. Change your form method from this **method="GET"** to this **method="POST"**.